# Radare -c but exit afterward

Tags: radare2

I'm using Radare to print out some information on blobs, essentially I'm running

```
radare2 -c "pf ... " ./myblob.bin
```

I would like radare to edit after it runs that `-c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radare calls this "quite mode" and provides two options,

```
-q    quiet mode (no prompt) and quit after -i
-Q    quiet mode (no prompt) and quit faster (quickLeak=true)
```

You can use them like this,

```
radare2 -qc "pf ... " ./myblob.bin
```

This will also suppress the annoying trivia/witty insult thing.

For a follow up question about -Q leaking,

- [Radare `-Q` leaking, and does it even matter?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18624/22669)