# Radare -Q leaking, and does it even matter?

Tags: radare2

[*As a follow up to a self-answered question where I discovered `-q` and `-Q`*](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18623/22669)

Radare `-Q` is documented as,

> `-Q` quiet mode (no prompt) and quit faster (`quickLeak=true`)

`man radare2` shows,

> `-Q` Same as `-q`, but exiting without freeing RCore, this produces leaks at exit time, but saves some precious ms to run the testsuite in fast mode.

Does not freeing RCore just mean that kernel does it for you when the processes terminates? Why would this even matter? Is there a downside to an app leaking on termination?

Comment: This is a software-development question and it is probably outside the scope of this community. You can find your answers on [Should I free memory before exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584062/should-i-free-memory-before-exit) and in [To free() or not to free() before an exit()](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/to-free-or-not-to-free-before-an-exit-458107/)

Comment: It doesn’t matter (the os will free everything), but this option was only made to make tests run faster...